# How to get the latest record in each group with ALL columns + a group count column per group?

Tags: postgresql

Consider the table:

```
CREATE TABLE event(
    event_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id UUID NOT NULL,
    trigger_id UUID NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    trigger_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    status smallint,
    date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
);
```

I want to

1) order by "type" ASC first, then by "date_created" DESC

This part is easily done like this

```
SELECT *
FROM event
WHERE user_id = 'fd80059a-3a16-40fe-9f6b-ad2812875d92'
ORDER BY type ASC, date_created DESC
```

2) group by "trigger_id", "type" and "name" with a count for each group. Yes I want to make a group if "trigger_id", "type" and "name" are the same, and show the most recent one with a count of all events in the group (basically how many times the event has occured, because if those 3 are the same, the event can considered to be related).

Here is the challenging part. Ideally something like this would work:

```
SELECT * --, count(since the count/grouping is based on 3 columns, how??)
FROM event
WHERE account_id = 'fd80059a-3a16-40fe-9f6b-ad2812875d92'
ORDER BY type ASC, date_created DESC
GROUP BY trigger_id, type, name
```

Would give me only the first record in each group (since they're already ordered by date), but with ALL it's columns (and not just the columns in the GROUP BY clause) + a group count column in the end.

I'm solving this now with option 1, and then using the following javascript code in my node API, but if you understand the snippet, it's doing exactly what I need to do in postgres:

```
[...arrayOfEventsFromDB.reduce((r, o) => {
    const key = `${o.trigger_id}-${o.type}-${o.name}`;

    const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
      count: 0,
    });

    item.count++;

    return r.set(key, item);
  }, new Map).values()];
```

But ideally, if postgres is a good fit for this kind of aggregation I'd like to to this within the SQL query.

Edit

Since I cannot paste code in comments to answers.

As requested here is a running fiddle with the table creation, data and the SELECT query I've come up with, by combining the 2 below answers. Seems a bit inefficient with all those subselects but works.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNNzwiDbx2iUdgd2vFTRuJ/0

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (trigger_id, type, name)
      *
      FROM (
          SELECT *,
          row_number () over(PARTITION BY trigger_id, type, name order by date_created DESC )
          FROM (
              SELECT
                  *,
                  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY trigger_id, type, name)
              FROM event
              WHERE user_id = 1
              ORDER BY type ASC, date_created DESC
          ) s
      ) t
  ) u
  ORDER BY type ASC, date_created DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to your rescue (Edit: And `DISTINCT ON` as well):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (type, date_created)
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY trigger_id, type, name)
    FROM event
    WHERE account_id = 'fd80059a-3a16-40fe-9f6b-ad2812875d92'
) s
ORDER BY type ASC, date_created DESC
```

---

Edit: After chatting this solution fits best:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (trigger_id, type, name)
        *
    FROM (
         SELECT *
         FROM (
             SELECT
                 *,
                 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY trigger_id, type, name)
             FROM event
             WHERE user_id = 1
         ) s
    ) t
    ORDER BY trigger_id, type, name, date_created DESC
) u
ORDER BY type ASC, date_created DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. While I get a count which is correct, I still get all records. Not in groups. I only want to show 4 records in the end. The latest one (based on date_created) for each group.

Comment: @Dac0d3r Updated. For more precise code I really need sample code and expected output (for that please edit your question)

Comment: Thanks alot. Please see my edit at the bottom of the post. I had to adjust it a little, but it seems to work. Just very slow, even with just 14 records in my table

Comment: Now please show us your data. 14 records shouldn't have such an impact. Maybe create a fiddle on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11

Comment: My bad, performance is decent. I think I had some network latency affecting it. I have to go not unfortunately, but will update later when I get back. I'll try to make a fiddle. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just added a fiddle and a working SQL query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNNzwiDbx2iUdgd2vFTRuJ/0 - not sure which of your 2 answers will be approved, since I used a little from you both to get it working. I guess the best answer will be an improved version of the SQL in the fiddle, since it has a lot of subselects. :D

Comment: @Dac0d3r https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4e26577df63cf8c0bfbb0bd6ed941cb3 Only adjusted the DISTINCT ON groups. No need for more subqueries. What is the row_number for? You never used it...

Comment: @Dac0d3r Nevertheless my answer seems to help you getting a valid solution. So please don't forget to upvote and maybe to accept

Comment: Row number is used to get the latest (by date_created) Per group . This is key! :-) also disti

Comment: also wrapped distinct with outer select to be able to order by date_created in addition to type, so yours is not really entirely correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196634/discussion-between-s-man-and-dac0d3r).

Answer (score 0):

You can check below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY trigger_id, type, name) cnt , row_number () over(PARTITION BY trigger_id, type, name order by date_created DESC ) rn
    FROM event a
    WHERE account_id = 'fd80059a-3a16-40fe-9f6b-ad2812875d92'
) s
where rn < = 4 
ORDER BY type ASC, date_created DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work, but your row_number trick seemed to be key to select just the first record per group. Based on your and S-man's answers I was able to put together a fiddle here, with a working SQL, however with all those nested subselects it seems like it is not the best implementation. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNNzwiDbx2iUdgd2vFTRuJ/0

Comment: @Dac0d3r Glad to know it helped. In case you got a better solution, you can post and accept the same. The final motive is to help each other and learn from each other.